# How can I give a logo a sticker effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

I'm new to graphic design and have started to use Adobe Illustrator. I was wondering if someone can tell me how to make the sticker pop up art like the Gowalla logo. Below is the logo that I'm referring to:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. So for I've been using the pen tool to make the white sticker area. Then I try to add an outer glow, but it doesn't look quite right. The most important thing I need help with is the shadow outlining to look crisp. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess this effect is called sticker effect and the white thing is an outline stroke near to 5 or 10 px and a shadow effect to glow the corners.
You can follow this tutorial for nearly output:

http://www.dezignmusings.com/2009/10/sticker-text-and-graphic-effect.html

Comment: I am also new to this graphics and [pop art](http://www.poparta.com/) but have learned quite a few techniques from the tutorial you provided.

Answer (score 6):

Do the vector art in Ai, as it is def a faster program for that, but you should probably save the shadow effects for Ps.

The shadow effect like that is done by a close shadow with a large size.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The drop shadow is what gives it the illusion that it has depth. Since you're using illustrator, you can apply a drop shadow to the white shape and adjust it how you see fit, including the sharpness of the drop shadow.

The drop shadow can be found under the effect menu...

**Effect** >> **Stylize** >> **Drop Shadow**

Blue determines the "sharpness" and the position of that shadow is determined by the x and y offsets